# Google Web Toolkit, append error

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, web

i have a problem, who can answer this ? Im tryng to program web app on GWT, and im having this error now, on this Line **TextArea.append(names[a]+"\n");** sorry for bad english. It says "The method append(String) is undefined for the type TextArea", how can i fix it ? pls  answer me

Comment: See which methods are available in this class and use the one you need, e.g. `setValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
textArea.setValue(names[a]+"\n")
```